# add to recycler view if URL is valid

Tags: android, multithreading, android-recyclerview, httpconnection

I want to check the URL in the edittext and if it was valid, add an item in recycler view. So for this purpose, I started a thread to check the HTTP connection.

```
 thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        String link = edt.getText().toString();
                        URL url = null;
                        try {
                            url = new URL(link);
                            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                            int code = connection.getResponseCode();

                            if(code == 200) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "reachable");
                                InsertItem(url,adapter);
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "in catch: not reachable");
                            }
                        }  catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                thread.start();
```

the problem is the error I get when try to add an item

```
 private void InsertItem(URL url, MyAdapter adapter) {
        thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        arrayList.add(0,new file(url.toString()));
        adapter.notifyItemChanged(0);
};
```

and the error is:

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.**

Looks like inside your new thread, you are calling InsertItem(url,adapter)(should begin with a lower case 'I') which is trying to perform some work on a UI element.

As the error states you cannot touch the views outside of the UI thread. You can try adding runOnUiThread(() -> insertItems(url,adapter) inside your thread to post the action to the UI thread.

Comment: thank you. how can I stop all the threads that I run? (new thread , runOnUiThread)

Comment: the runOnUiThread you dont need to manage, its just a way to preform some action on android main thread.

You can call interrupt on your new thread in the same way as before if your move your runOnUiThread block into insertItem() method and before call thread.interrupt()